# If an algebra is free on a set, that set is linearly independant

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, algebras

Let $R$ be a ring (commutative with unit), and $E$ a set.
We denote $A$ the free $R$-algebra on $E$.

**Note.** $A$ is a non-commutative algebra.

I wanted to show that if we consider $A$ as a left $A$-module, then the set $E$ is $A$-linearly independant. That is, if $\sum_{e \in E} a_e e_e = 0$, then $a_e = 0$ for all $e \in E$ (**Note.** $a_e \in A$).

Since $A$ is free on $E$, we already know that the set of all words in E and the empty word form an $R$-basis of $A$. I think with that I have all I need for the proof, but I miss something on how to use this fact.

Any hint or help would be great.

Best regards.

K. Y.

Comment: this is certainly not true, since every element of $E$ is an element of $A$. so for instance, for any $e_1,e_2\in E$, if $a_1=e_2$ and $a_2=-e_1$ then $a_1e_1+a_2e_2=0$.

Comment: I edited the question. Note that the algebra $A$ is not commutative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $E = \{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$ and assume $\sum_{i=1}^n a_ie_i = 0$ with $a_i \in A$. Every $a_i$ can be [uniquely written](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_algebra) as
\begin{equation}
a_i = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{i_1, \ldots, i_k \in \{1, \ldots, n\}} a^{(i)}_{i_1,\ldots, i_k} e_{i_1}\ldots e_{i_k}\tag{1}\end{equation}
for some $a^{(i)}_{i_1,\ldots, i_k} \in R$ with at most finitely many of them nonzero. Plugging this in we get
\begin{align}
0 &= \sum_{i=1}^n a_ie_i \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{i_1, \ldots i_k \in \{1, \ldots, n\}} a^{(i)}_{i_1,\ldots, i_k} e_{i_1}\ldots e_{i_k}\right)e_i\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{i_1, \ldots i_k \in \{1, \ldots, n\}} a^{(i)}_{i_1,\ldots, i_k} e_{i_1}\ldots e_{i_k}e_i\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{i_1, \ldots, i_k,i \in  \{1, \ldots, n\}} a^{(i)}_{i_1,\ldots, i_k} e_{i_1}\ldots e_{i_k}e_i.
\end{align}
Now the monomials $e_{i_1}\ldots e_{i_k}e_i$ are all different since they are parameterized by $(i_1, \ldots, i_k,i) \in \{1,\ldots, n\}^{k+1}$ so by definition it follows that all scalars are $0$:
$$a^{(i)}_{i_1,\ldots, i_k}=0, \quad \forall i_1, \ldots, i_k,i \in  \{1, \ldots, n\}.$$

Therefore $(1)$ implies  $a_i = 0$ for all $1 \le i \le n$ so $E$ is $A$-linearly independent.